# mysql install problem on ubuntu vps . An error like below

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, nginx, vps

mysql installation problem

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Errors we
re encountered while processing:
mysql-server-8.0
mysql-server
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)